# Left join the same table with Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, dql

I'm going to run the following MySQL query with Doctrine (it works as expected on MySQL side):

```sql
select latest.product_id, latest.last_read_at
from attributes latest
left join attributes bigger
    on latest.product_id = bigger.product_id and
       latest.last_read_at <= bigger.last_read_at and
       latest.id < bigger.id
where bigger.last_read_at is null;
```

Here is my try with Doctrine:

```php
$queryBuilder = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
        $categoryVersions = $queryBuilder
            ->select('latest.product_id', 'latest.last_read_at')
            ->from($entityClass, 'latest')
            ->leftJoin(
                $entityClass,
                'bigger',
                Join::ON,
                $queryBuilder->expr()->andX(
                    $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('latest.product_id', 'bigger.product_id'),
                    $queryBuilder->expr()->lte('latest.last_read_at', 'bigger.last_read_at'),
                    $queryBuilder->expr()->lt('latest.id', 'bigger.id')
                )
            )
            ->where('bigger.last_read_at is NULL')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
```

Which transforms into DQL:

```
SELECT latest.product_id, latest.last_read_at
FROM My\Namespace\Entity\Attribute latest
LEFT JOIN My\Namespace\Entity\Attribute bigger ON
    latest.product_id = bigger.product_id AND  
    latest.last_read_at <= bigger.last_read_at AND
    latest.id < bigger.id
WHERE bigger.last_read_at is NULL
```

And here is the result:

```
[Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException]                                      
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 156: Error: Expected end of string, got 'ON'
```

Can you please help me with building the correct DQL?